# How do I authorize using Spotipy on Django?

Tags: python, django, api, spotipy

I am having a great deal of trouble trying to authorize Spotipy. It does fine in IDLE, but as soon I try to do it together with Django, hell lets loose. Where I have gotten the farthest, is where I have gotten the code from the callback. But what do I do after that?
This piece of code below takes

```
def add_song(request, pk, uri):
    scope = "user-read-recently-played user-top-read user-read-playback-position user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state user-read-currently-playing user-read-private playlist-modify-private playlist-read-private"
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token("username", scope, client_id=SECRET,client_secret=SECRET,redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/rooms/callback/')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    sp.add_to_queue(uri)

    auth_manager = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(scope='user-read-currently-playing playlist-modify-private', show_dialog=True)
    
    
    if request.GET.get("code"):
        # Step 3. Being redirected from Spotify auth page
        auth_manager.get_access_token(request.GET.get("code"))
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'rooms/{0}.html'.format(pk))

def callback(request):    
    return redirect(reverse("index"))
```

The URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/add_song/<str:uri>', views.add_song, name='add_song'),
    path('callback/<str:token>', views.callback, name="callback")
]
```

I really need something to continue on. I have been googling so much, but there isn't really anything I know what to do with. Could you provide an example of Django Python authorization or try to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `util.prompt_for_user_token`. Assuming you want different users to use your app, how would you pre-know their username?

Use a `SpotifyOAuth` object instead (you were using it, just not in the way I'm about to show). You can refer to the Client `Authorization Code Flow` section on the official docs.

Here is the basic of it:

```
# Seprating the login from add_song()
def login(request):
        sp_auth = SpotifyOAuth(
        scope=scope,
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        )
        # This url will prompt you a Spotify login page, then redirect user to your /callback upon authorization
        redirect_url = sp_auth.get_authorize_url() # Note: You should parse this somehow. It may not be in a pretty format.
        return redirect(redirect_url)

# You can make add_song() and callback() the same function. 
# If you have multiple pages where you need to use the API, I suggest caching the token here as well.
def callback_and_add_song():
        sp_auth = [the same as above. You should make a method to modularize it.]
        # Get code from url
        code = request.GET.get("code", "")
        token = sp_auth.get_access_token(code=code)
        <You have token now. Do what you need.>
```

A few more things I noticed in your code that may be not-needed/ wrong:

1. `path('callback/<str:token>'`: I don't think `<str:token>` have to be there.
2. `return redirect('/')`: In the first `if` in `add_song()`, assuming your previous code works, you are still just redirecting somewhere without caching the token/ passing it on.
3. `return redirect(reverse("index"))`: The same as above. I think for performance and all, you should cache token in callback() then redirect to page(s) where you actually use it.